# How to i find records in the last month that do not have a "Date created" column

Tags: sql

Im trying to find records that have not had notes created during the last 1 month. The table only registers when a note is created.

I am trying to find `NULL` values, but that would not be the correct logic

```
SELECT * 
FROM vpersonnotesalldata AS pn
WHERE pn.flddatecreated > '20190501' 
AND pn.fldnotedatecreated < '20190530'
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, no images.

Comment: add sample data

Comment: Client fldClientStatus  fldClientNumber fldFacility  LastNote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Column data types? Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time , many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: This only provides NULL values, however not in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want records which don't have a note in last 30 days, try this:

```
select p.* from person p where personid not in (
    select personid from Note where dateCreated < dateadd(d, -30, GetDate())
)
```

Obviously use your actual table names in your sql

Comment: this only joins all notes with person as each person can have hundreds on notes. Essentially in the health care sector, each client can have multiple notes, we want to find customers who have not had a note entered in the last 30 days

Comment: select p.* from person p where personid not in (select personid from Note where dateCreated < dateadd(d, -30, GetDate())

Comment: select p.fldFirstName 

from tblPerson p where p.fldPersonID not in (select p.fldPersonID from tblPersonNotes pn where pn.fldDateCreated < dateadd(d, -30, GetDate()) - this returns an error  (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
)

Comment: missing bracket

Comment: I get the logic :D and gives me axactly what i need :)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with example last month

```
SELECT *
FROM vpersonnotesalldata AS pn
WHERE pn.NoteColumnHERE IS NULL 
AND pn.CreateDateColumnHERE
    BETWEEN '01.05.2019'
    AND     '31.05.2019'
```

It picks all pn.NoteColumnHERE which are NULL in the Span of pn.CreateDateColumnHERE BETWEEN 01.05. and 31.05.

I hope the Date Input is correct for your SQL Version. In Microsoft SQL it is working!

Comment: This won’t work as there are no null VALUES. only the date created stamp

Answer (score 0):

The performance will be much better if you use EXISTS / NOT EXISTS instead of IN / NOT IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM Client C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM vpersonnotesalldata
    WHERE 
        fldClientNumber = C.fldClientNumber 
        AND fldnotedatecreated BETWEEN 
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) --First day of previous month
            AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) --Last Day of previous month
)
```